# Wrong checkbox is activated when *ngFor iterated <span> is clicked in Angular 2

Tags: angular

Here's the issue: [image: UI error]

When I click on the text/span section of an element, the first checkbox in the section is selected. If I click on the checkbox only, the UI functions as expected. The `amenityEmit(payloadObj)` function works as intended, this is only a UI issue. (I think.)

How do I get the proper checkbox to be selected when its associated `<span><input ... />{{instance}}</span>` is clicked?

Code:

```
<label *ngSwitchCase="'checkbox'" class="filter-category-title">
  {{f.name}}
  <div class="filterSection">
    <span *ngFor="let instance of f.options" class="filterOption">
      <input type="checkbox"
          (click)="amenityEmit(
              {category: f.propName, filter: instance, resetCategory: false}
            )"> {{instance}}
    </span>
  </div>
</label>
```

Comment: It might be a good idea to put the inputs in there own components and use @Input() and @Output() to pass values in and out.

Comment: Exactly then the checkbox is contained and separated from your main body of code.

Comment: Are you suggesting that each checkbox in a set should be its own component? (eg., fireplace, dishwasher, furnished are each individual components?) Or are you suggesting that the `.filterSection` class should be its own component, and that would fix the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be the `<label></label>` that is wrapping around everything

Give this a shot, and wrap `label` around just the `input` and the text beside the input

### **[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/vqd1BEHiVq2fLBxHNNB8?p=preview)** Demo

```
<div *ngSwitchCase="'checkbox'" class="filter-category-title">
  {{f.name}}
  <div class="filterSection">
    <label *ngFor="let instance of f.options" class="filterOption">
      <input type="checkbox"
          (click)="amenityEmit(
              {category: f.propName, filter: instance, resetCategory: false}
            )"> {{instance}}
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

It may mess with some of your css but if it fixes the bug then some css tweaks are minor

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing this is to write a CheckboxComponent and use that, data then can be past in and out and contain the click function within each component.

*checkbox.component.html*

```
<input type="checkbox" (click)="amenityEmit()"> {{instance}}
```

*checkbox.component.ts*

```
import { Component, Input, Output } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
     selector: "checkbox",
     //template and css stuff
})
export class CheckboxComponent {

    @Output() public value: any = new EventEmitter()    

    @Input() public options: OptionsObject;

    public amenityEmit(): void {

        this.value.emit({
            category: f.propName, 
            filter: instance, 
            resetCategory: false
        });
    }    
}
```

*ParentComponent*

```
<label *ngSwitchCase="'checkbox'" class="filter-category-title">
    {{f.name}}
    <div class="filterSection">
        <checkbox *ngFor="let instance of f.options" [options]="instance" (value)="amenityEmit($event)"></checkbox>
    </div>
</label>
```

A different approach and perhaps makes the code in the parent component a little cleaner.